# How to append an iterator index number to each item within an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, iterator

How do you append a key called 'Index' with a value being the dictionaries index to the below array? The array should be sorted by Timestamp before this occurs so that TimeStamp:111 comes first and TimeStamp:222 comes second, etc.

For example, see below for original array

```
items = [
            {Id: "01", Name: "A", Price: "1.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:111},
            {Id: "02", Name: "B", Price: "10.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:222},
            {Id: "04", Name: "C", Price: "9.50", Quantity: "10",TimeStamp:434},
            {Id: "03", Name: "a", Price: "9.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:545},
            {Id: "06", Name: "b", Price: "100.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:676},
            {Id: "05",Name: "c", Price: "1.20", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:777}
        ];
```

The resulting array should look like this:

```
items = [
    {Id: "01", Name: "A", Price: "1.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:111,Index:1},
            {Id: "02", Name: "B", Price: "10.00", Quantity: "1",TimeStamp:222,Index:2},
            {Id: "04", Name: "C", Price: "9.50", Quantity: "10",TimeStamp:434,Index:3},
            {Id: "03", Name: "a", Price: "9.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:545,Index:4},
            {Id: "06", Name: "b", Price: "100.00", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:676,Index:5},
            {Id: "05",Name: "c", Price: "1.20", Quantity: "2",TimeStamp:777,Index:6}
        ];
```

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/f7dnfrjf/
I've figured out how to append an item to each dictionary, but not how to append its respective iterator.

Also, here it is in angular js (bonus points if there is a way to do it with angular): http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/GgjGvO?editors=101

Comment: what is the purpose? Angular already provides access to `$index` in `ng-repeat` if that is what it is used  for

Comment: that's a great question and gets to the core of my issue. The issue is that $index would work great if it provided the same index of an item in the array whether it was filtered or not. In other words, if the third item of the original array is filtered out, 3 would then be assigned to another item, which I don't want. See this codepen for what I mean: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/GgjGvO?editors=101. Notice that $index returns 1 for 'a' even though it is the third item. Is there a better way to do do this in angular?

Comment: use `track by $index`

Comment: Thanks! Your questioning did led me to find a better solution overall by using indexOf. See new codepen here for anyone else with similar issue: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/pvEKpB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index started from 0, so you need add `+1` for each index, like this

```
items.forEach(function (d, index) {
    d.Index = index + 1;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f7dnfrjf/1/

*Angular demos:*

1. [http://codepen.io/pen/ZYpRag](http://codepen.io/tarasyuk/pen/ZYpRag) - indexes are displayed as 2, 3, 5, 6
2. [http://codepen.io/pen/zxKapG](http://codepen.io/tarasyuk/pen/zxKapG) - indexes are displayed as 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

The runtime system passes 3 parameters to `.forEach()`: the first is the array element, the second is the index, and the third is the array itself.

Thus:

```
items.forEach(function (d, i) {
    d.Index = i;
});
```